# Plylab / MatPlotLib plot not showing data properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been following a tutorial to learn about fft and although I have the code verbatum, the plot from my machine does not look how it ought to.  I log the data to make sure that I have an approximate sine wav over 5292 samples.  However when I run the plot with `show()` I get the following image:  (btw, is there a markdown attr for making these images smaller?)

[image: pyplot]

Again, this is generated from the subsequent code:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.io import wavfile


sampFreq, snd = wavfile.read('440_sine.wav')

snd = snd / (2.**15)

s1 = snd[:,0]

timeArray = arange(0, 5292, 1)
timeArray = timeArray / sampFreq
timeArray = timeArray * 1000  #scale to milliseconds


plot(timeArray, s1, color='k')
ylabel('Amplitude')
xlabel('Time (ms)')


for i in s1:
    print i

show()
```

In short, I'm learning about fft and I'm a newcomer to python/matplotlib, so any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of your `sampFreq`? Your `timeArray` is an integer list and I am assuming sampFreq is returned an integer as well. If `sampFreq` is larger than the values in `timeArray` then all of the resultant values will be 0 because integer division.

You may want to cast `sampFreq` to a float first before diving through the `timeArray` list and see if that helps.

As an example of the issue, in python shell try out:

```
>>> 3/4
```

and

```
>>> 3/4.0
```